# error in Multiple Select statements in Insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am writing a query which has multiple select statements in an insert statement

```
    INSERT INTO dbo.Products 
    (ProductName, 
     SupplierID, 
     CategoryID, 
     UnitsInStock, 
     UnitsOnOrder, 
     ReorderLevel, 
     Discontinued)
VALUES  
    ('Twinkies' , 
     (SELECT SupplierID FROM dbo.Suppliers WHERE CompanyName = 'Lyngbysild'),
     (SELECT CategoryID FROM dbo.Categories WHERE CategoryName = 'Confections'), 
     0, 
     0, 
     10, 
     0)
```

Actually it gives error

```
Msg 1046, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Where these two select statements returns only one value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change VALUES to SELECT and remove the outer parentheses.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Products 
(ProductName, 
 SupplierID, 
 CategoryID, 
 UnitsInStock, 
 UnitsOnOrder, 
 ReorderLevel, 
 Discontinued)
SELECT  
'Twinkies' , 
 (SELECT SupplierID FROM dbo.Suppliers WHERE CompanyName = 'Lyngbysild'),
 (SELECT CategoryID FROM dbo.Categories WHERE CategoryName = 'Confections'), 
 0, 
 0, 
 10, 
 0
```

You may also need a `TOP 1` on the subexpressions, but that would give a different error message: subquery returned more than one value.

Comment: I am following this solution, but it returns ``Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.``.  How should I fix this?

Comment: @overloading, the error means just that it says.  You have to modify the sub-select to be sure that there is no more than one result.  How you do that will depend on your situation.  In T-SQL, you can use a `TOP 1` with `ORDER BY` to limit the results, or you can specify further `WHERE` conditions.  It really depends on what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks!  Its working now but am not sure why it works.  Here's my original statement: ``INSERT INTO someTable(Date, Id, Constant) SELECT GETDATE(), Id FROM otherTable where Id IN(1,2), 10`` this returns the more than 1 value error.  But when I do this: ``SELECT GETDATE(), Id, 10 FROM otherTable where Id IN(1,2);`` this would work.  Could you explain to me why this works? Isnt it still returning 2 rows as result?

Comment: @overloading, your first statement is not valid syntax.  Note that the "more than one value" issue only applies to *sub-selects*, since they have to fill one cell in the output.  You can do an `INSERT..SELECT` with as many rows as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Error message is correct, since

```
SELECT SupplierID FROM dbo.Suppliers WHERE CompanyName = 'Lyngbysild'
```

Can (technically) return multiple rows, which row should it display in the column?

If you know that this subquery will only return one row, then tell the database to take the first one.

```
SELECT TOP 1 SupplierID FROM dbo.Suppliers WHERE CompanyName = 'Lyngbysild'
```